# How to add a semi colon ; automatically to each generated sql statement using jOOQ

Tags: sql, jooq

I'm trying to add a semi colon `;` to every jOOQ generated sql statement as I'm writing multiple DDL and insert statement to an output file.

I found a similar question here suggesting using an `ExecuteListener` here https://jooq-user.narkive.com/6adKecpt/adding-semicolon-at-the-end-of-sql-statement.

My setup is now as follows (using Groovy):

```
    private DSLContext createDSLContext() {
        def configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
        configuration.settings = new Settings()
                .withRenderFormatted(true)
                .withRenderKeywordCase(RenderKeywordCase.LOWER)
                .withRenderQuotedNames(RenderQuotedNames.ALWAYS)
                .withStatementType(StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT)
        configuration.set(
                new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new DefaultExecuteListener() {
                    @Override
                    void renderEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
                        ctx.sql(ctx.sql() + ";")
                    }
                }),
                new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new DefaultExecuteListener() {
                    @Override
                    void start(ExecuteContext ctx) {
                        println "YEAH!!!"
                    }
                }))
        // return configuration.dsl();
        return DSL.using(configuration)
    }
```

but is not adding the semi colon, nor is it getting in the `renderEnd` method at all.
I added another execute listener to print something at the start (as I have seen in other examples) but it is also never called..

My code looks like:

```
        file.withWriter { writer ->

            // Drop schema objects.

            DEFAULT_SCHEMA.tables.each {
                switch (it.type) {
                    case TABLE:
                        writer.writeLine(dsl.dropTableIfExists(it).SQL)
                        break
                    case VIEW:
                        writer.writeLine(dsl.dropViewIfExists(it).SQL)
                        break
                }
            }
            writer.writeLine("")

            // Create schema objects.

            def ddlStatements = dsl.ddl(DEFAULT_SCHEMA)
            ddlStatements.each {
                writer.writeLine(it.SQL)
                writer.writeLine("")
            }

            // Insert data.

            def insert = dsl.insertInto(Tales.CUSTOMER).columns(Tales.CUSTOMER.fields())
            customers.each {insert.values(it) }
            writer.writeLine(insert.SQL)

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExecuteListener` lifecycle is only triggered when you *execute* your queries with jOOQ. You're not doing that, you're just calling [`Query.getSQL()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL())

You could wrap your queries into [`DSLContext.queries(Query...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#queries(org.jooq.Query...)), and jOOQ will separate the statements using `;` when you call `Queries.getSQL()` when you call `Queries.toString()`. Of course, that's not reliable, the behaviour of `toString()` might change in the future, which is why it would make sense to offer methods like `Queries.getSQL()` and the likes: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11755

For the time being, why not just add the semi colon manually to the `writer` in your code?

Comment: Yes, that's my alternative at the moment do add the semi colons manually. As I have to do it in multiple places - and I forgot one ;-) - I looked if jOOQ could do it instead and I read about the `ExecuteListener `. I now understand that it is only used where executing queries using jOOQ. Thx!